# MongoDB Injection: Escaping User Input for Use with the $where Operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, escaping, code-injection

I'm doing research on injection vulnerabilities with MongoDB. Of course, one  of the main culprits is the `$where` operator. While the best advice might certainly be to avoid using this operator whenever possible, I'm trying to understand how to safely escape user input in cases when `$where` might actually be in use.

A trivial example:

```
db.foo.find({$where: 'this.value === ' + userInput})
```

The [MongoDB FAQ](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/index.html) provides a hint at how this might be done:

> If you need to pass user-supplied values in a $where clause, you may escape these values with the CodeWScope mechanism. When you set user-submitted values as variables in the scope document, you can avoid evaluating them on the database server.

However I've been unable to find good information on the `CodeWScope` mechanism, specifically:

1. How to go about using this mechanism, especially with the Node driver for MongoDB, in the context of input escaping for use with `$where` or anything else.
2. A description on what it actually does, i.e., how it escapes values and/or mitigates injection attacks.

The [MongoDB Node Driver API Reference](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Code.html) documents a class called `Code`, which might in fact be *the* "CodeWScope mechanism", but the reference is sparse and there are no usage examples and no description that illuminates the actual mechanism:

> **Code**
>
> `new Code(code, scope)`
>
> A class representation of the BSON Code type.
>
> **Param**: `code` **Type**: `string | function` **Desc**: `a string or function`
>
> **Param**: `scope` **Type**: `Object` **Desc**: `an optional scope for the function.`

Other references, such as [BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) offer almost nothing on the subject.

I'm looking for guidance and information on:

- What is the CodeWScope mechanism?
- How do I use it with the Node driver?
- How does MongoDB evaluate CodeWScope-wrapped values to mitigate or prevent injection attacks?
- Is there better documentation on its use, or examples/tutorials, than I've been able to uncover?